# What is the Borel sigma-field of positive functions?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, borel-sets, random-functions

I was reading the paper ["The Logistic Normal Distribution for Bayesian, Nonparametric, Predictive Densities" published in 1988 in Journal of the American Statistical Association by Peter J. Lenk](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288870?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

At the beginning of the paper, the author mentions a sigma-algebra that I don't understand. His goal is to work with random pdf afterwards and he states that for a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and a space $X$:

> *[A random pdf]* $f$ is modelled by a stochastic process from $\Omega \times X$ to $\mathbb R^+$, the positive reals such that the sample
> paths integrate to $1$. With this goal in mind, $\mathbb {R^{+}}^X$ is
> the space of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R^+$ with the Borel
> sigma-field $B(X, \mathbb R^+)$.

I don't understand what the Borel sigma-field mentionned is supposed to be, as the topology considered was not specified. Is there a "standard"/"canonical" choice of topology that allows to define this sigma-algebra, or is it an imprecision in the paper ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, no special topological hypothesis is made concerning $X$, so one must assume that  by $B(S,\Bbb R^+)$ the author intends the product $\sigma$-field on $(\Bbb R^+)^X$. As the author intends to integrate $f(\omega, y)$ with respect to $y$ and thereby obtain  $\mathcal F$-*measurable* functions like  $\omega\mapsto\int_A f(\omega,y)d\lambda(y)$, one really needs (to use Fubini) to assume that $(\omega,y)\mapsto f(\omega,y)$ is is $\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal X$-measurable, where $\mathcal X$ is the $\sigma$-field on $X$ upon which $\lambda$ is defined. This implies that for each Borel subset   $B\subset\Bbb R^+$ and each $y\in X$,
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega,y)\in B\}
$$
is $\mathcal F$-measurable. This is enough to guarantee that $\omega\mapsto   f(\omega,\cdot)$, viewed as a map from $\Omega$ to $(\Bbb R^+)^X$ is $\mathcal F/B(S,\Bbb R^+)$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explainations regarding the joint measurability requirements. I still don't understand one thing: you said that $B(S, \mathbb{R}^+)$  (or $B(X, \mathbb{R}^+)$ if we keep the article notations) is the product $\sigma-$field on $(\mathbb{R}^+)^X$, but $(\mathbb{R}^+)^X$ is not a countable product of set. How to define the *product* $\sigma-$field in this setting ?

Comment: Hello, after further reading on the topic, I now have a better understanding of what is the product $\sigma$-field for an uncountable product of set. Thank you again for your answer!